# Edges become sharp after flip normal

Tags: normals

I import a model from binary data and figure out that its normal vectors are in wrong direction. After flipping vectors, the faces do not look smooth like before although I try to use "Shading/Smooth faces" and "Clear sharps" feature. How could I do to make the face look smooth in this case? I attached the .blend file here. Thanks.
[Download sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QhicplAob9TiKRL9PpbDrDSymU-MLimb/view?usp=sharing)

Before flipping normals
[image: Before flipping normals]

After flipping normals
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mesh has 211 double vertices that mess up the shading.

Select all vertices (<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>), disable *Autosmooth* and go:

1. *Mesh > Clean up > Merge by distance* (this will merge 211 double vertices)
2. *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate outside*
3. *RMB > Shade Smooth*

This will ensure you have a clean mesh, normals pointing out and proper shading.

[image]